# Uncaught TypeError: div.css is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was trying to dynamically change the `background-color` of the div but unfortunately  I cant seem to make it work! Please let me know what's wrong with my codes.

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var categorydivs = $(".category-container");
        $.each(categorydivs,function(index,div){
            div.css("background-color","yellow");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="category-container">
        Category 1
    </div>
    <div class="category-container">
        Category 2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After running the codes above it will throw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: div.css is not a function`. **Why?**

Comment: convert div to jquery objcet https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/30/

Comment: No need to loop-through for each div of the same class . it is possible by only one statement `$(".category-container").css("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: @vohuman.. This question can't be duplicate as it has different anwer than the one you have suggested

Comment: @captainsac And what is that difference? FYI both `div` and the `this` keyword refer to **the same element**.

Comment: @vohuman it has a completely different answer and analysis. It can be concluded as there is no need of 'loop' in the code provided. hence the answer is completely different.

Comment: @captainsac "t has a completely different answer and analysis". No it doesn't. This is an exact duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`div` inside `each` is not the jQuery `object` it is the `HTML` element, so you cannot call jQuery methods on it.

You can use `$(this)` inside `each` to get the current `div` instance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var categorydivs = $(".category-container");
    $.each(categorydivs, function (index, div) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3cyaechu/)

You don't need to loop for adding css to all elements. Use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".category-container").css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: DownVoters, please explain here why downvoted?

Comment: Does the loop really required for this operation??

Comment: @captainsac No. Please check updated answer. Thanks for hint

Comment: @Tushar this question is marked as duplicate which is not correct as it has completely different view than that of the question suggested. Kindly comment to the flagger

Comment: @captainsac No. the question is really duplicate, if you look at the original question

Comment: Questions are similar but the way of analysis and answer are different.

Comment: @captainsac The answer is different, but the question is duplicated

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:-
`$(this).css("background-color","yellow");` instead of `div.css("background-color","yellow");`

Comment: div is just simple value of the '$.each(categorydivs' where as $(this) is the jquery object, so you can use its various functions like 'css,attr' etc.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
div.css("background-color","yellow");
```

Change to:

```
$(div).css("background-color","yellow");
```

Regards.